# pod install shows the following issues

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cocoapods

```
    [!] The `DRN1 [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DRN1/Pods-DRN1.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `DRN1 [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DRN1/Pods-DRN1.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `DRN1 [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DRN1/Pods-DRN1.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `DRN1 [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DRN1/Pods-DRN1.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] FBSDKMessengerShareKit has been deprecated
```

I am wondering what all this means as my app is throwing errors since switching from the SDK version to pod install version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try add `$(inherited)` and `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to Debug and Release like image below

[image]